# Cannot find pipe symbol "|" in Ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, keyboard, shortcut-keys

This question might sound silly, but I'm trying to install `webmin` on Ubuntu server and I need to execute this command:

```
wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

but I'm unable to do it, because I cannot use the pipe symbol "|". I've tried every key from my keyboard, as well single key and combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>.
I cannot copy paste as well, because <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work neither (though I've enabled common buffer for my pc and virtual machine).

What else can I do here?

Comment: you may want to look for the character somewhere in a file and copy it from there.

Comment: Did you set the correct keyboard layout in your VM? Also try key combinations with `AltGr` or `Shift`+`AltGr`.

Comment: i) please [edit] your question and tell us what keyboard layout you are using; ii) on Linux, selecting something with the mouse copies it and middle-clicking pastes it. No need for Ctrl+V or anything else. You can also select and right click -> copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the keyboard layout:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Alternatively, you can set *XKBLAYOUT* value in the keyboard config file /etc/default/keyboard

Then, apply the change by running:

```
$ sudo setupcon
```

Comment: Thank you, changing keyboard layout actually solved the problem.

Comment: what keyboard layout should i use though?

Comment: Thanks so much. That fixed my problem.